# How can we find the system service name of oracle db?

Tags: linux, oracle12c

when I run `ps -ef` it is showing something like this

> oracle    42547      1  0 Mar14 ?        00:00:35 asm_pmon_+ASM

Help me to find exact service name for oracle Database.

Comment: Can you please write the full command you typed in ? Also what possible could be service name for oracle database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ps -ef | grep pmon
```

will show you all the processes monitor processes running in the server.

In your case, it shows `asm_pmon_+ASM` is the name of the process, which means,
 `+ASM` is one of your instances running.

to extract `+ASM` only from the text, use:

```
ps -ef | grep "[p]mon" | awk -F "_" '{ print $NF }'.
```

Another option is to use `pgrep pmon` instead of `ps -ef | grep ..`

It is pretty straightforward when you are connected to the database instead.

```
select sys_context('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME') from dual;
```